# Three.js LegacyGLTFLoader.js shadows missing

Tags: three.js, gltf

I have a GLTF version 1.0 model that I am importing into Three.js using LegacyGLTFLoader.js.  When I do so, everything looks good, except that the model does not receive shadows.  I am guessing that this is because the imported model's material is THREE.RawShaderMaterial, which does not support receiving shadows (I think).  How can I fix this so that my imported model can receive shadows?

Here is sample code:

```
// Construct scene.
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Get window dimensions.
var width = window.innerWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight;

// Construct camera.
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, width/height);
camera.position.set(20, 20, 20);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

// Construct renderer.
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(width, height);
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Construct cube.
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 1, 10);
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial);
cube.castShadow = true;
cube.translateY(15);
scene.add(cube);

// Construct floor.
var floorGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 1, 20);
var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x00ffff});
var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
floor.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(floor);

// Construct light.
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
light.position.set(0, 20, 0);
light.castShadow = true;
scene.add(light);

// Construct light helper.
var lightHelper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(light);
scene.add(lightHelper);

// Construct orbit controls.
new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

// Construct GLTF loader.
var loader = new THREE.LegacyGLTFLoader();

// Load GLTF model.
loader.load(
    "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5piiujui3sdiaj3/1.glb",
    function(event) {
        var model = event.scene.children[0];
        var mesh = model.children[0];
        mesh.receiveShadow = true;
        scene.add(model);
    },
    null,
    function(event) {
        alert("Loading model failed."); 
    }
);

// Animates the scene.
var animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

// Animate the scene.
animate();
```

Here are my resources:

- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/y2r8bsrppv0oqp4/three.js
- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5wh92lnsxz2ge1e/LegacyGLTFLoader.js
- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1jygy1eavetnp0d/OrbitControls.js
- https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/5piiujui3sdiaj3/1.glb

Here is a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rmilbert/8tqc3yx4/26/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix the problem is to replace the instance of `RawShaderMaterial` with `MeshStandardMaterial`. To get the intended effect, you have to apply the existing texture to the new material like so:

```js
var newMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( { roughness: 1, metalness: 0 } ); 
newMaterial.map = child.material.uniforms.u_tex.value;
```

You also have to compute normal data for the respective geometry so lighting can be computed correctly. If you need no shadows, the unlint `MeshBasicMaterial` is actually the better choice.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e67hbj1q/2/